# Can I use one instance variable to point to different objects over its lifetime?

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple question about using a pointer in Obj-C.

Is it bad practice to use one pointer for different instances of the same thing?

For example, if I have an UIViewController Class called Poster and I am using it in a UIViewController Class called MovieTheater

in MovieTheater.h:

```
@interface MovieTheater : UIViewController {
    Poster *newMoviePoster;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Poster *newMoviePoster;

- (void) changePoster:(NSString*)titleText;
```

Then in MovieTheater.m:

```
@synthesize newMoviePoster;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
  newMoviePoster = [[Poster alloc]initWithTitle:@"COMING IN MAY"];



}

-(void) changePoster:(NSString*)titleText{

    newMoviePoster= [[Poster alloc]initWithTitle:titleText];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[newMoviePoster release];
}
```

Let's assume that we need to access the newMoviePoster object often, so releasing it before viewDidUnload breaks the app.

Is this legit code? It looks good to me, but I am relatively new in Obj-C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine to do, **except** that you need to release the old instance of `newMoviePoster` before assigning the new one:

```
-(void) changePoster:(NSString*)titleText{
    [newMoviePoster release]
    newMoviePoster= [[Poster alloc]initWithTitle:titleText];
}
```

Or, use the synthesized setter:

```
self.newMoviePoster = [[[Poster alloc] initWithTitle:titleText] autorelease];
```

Comment: Using the synthesized setter with `initWithTitle:` would over-retain.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong, it’s leaking memory. When you create a new object using the `alloc` call, you get a pointer to the allocated memory that you have to later `release`. You store this value to the `newMoviePoster` variable – so far so good. But when you call `changePoster:`, you overwrite the previous pointer with a new one. The old pointer to the allocated memory is gone and you will not be able to release the memory, it’s lost until your program quits.

This is easy to fix, but what really needs fixing is your understanding of Cocoa memory management. You could start by reading the [Cocoa Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), that’s a must reading for any Cocoa programmer.

As for the original question, it’s fine to use one variable to point to several different objects over its lifetime. But it’s better to avoid it if possible, because it’s prone to bugs, as you have seen just now. This is one of the reasons why some programmers try to keep values from changing, see [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutable) and [functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming).

Comment: This would fix that, corect:-(void) changePoster:(NSString*)titleText{
    [newMoviePoster release]
    newMoviePoster= [[Poster alloc]initWithTitle:titleText];
}

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. (But it’s imperative that you have solid understanding of the Cocoa memory management, otherwise you will waste much more time than it would take you to read the guide three times through.)

Comment: Proper use of properties also helps to avoid the kind of bugs that @Buyin is seeing.

Comment: @kubi: True, but it’s still much too easy to do `self.foo = [[Bar alloc] init]`, forget to `release` in `dealloc` or do other mistakes  if you don’t really know what’s happening. Cocoa memory management is so easy that it’s a pity not to know it by heart.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, self.foo = [[Bar alloc] init] doesn't have to be released? I though all alloc/inits had to be released

Comment: If `foo` is declared as retained property, doing `self.foo = [[Bar alloc] init]` is wrong and will leak, because you have +2 retain count on `foo` (one for `alloc`, one for going through the setter) and `foo` will only be released once when you do `self.foo = somethingElse`.

Comment: Thanks zoul, I didn't know that the setter added to the retain count. I will brush up on the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention when you keep pointers to an instance, it could cause some nightmare bugs if you're trying to use the pointer to an object that was autoreleased, or released by your own code and even worse : released automatically after a memoy warning.

Finding the error origin could be almost impossible.

Comment: in the example above, I only release the object on viewDidUnload, would that prevent the issue you describe?

Comment: that's why you should use proper memory management with balanced retain/releases. The result will be nightmare free code.